# How to solve empty costume list view issue?

Tags: android, android-listview

I have written a code to get all the videos related to a specific user in YouTube as follows:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HTTP;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.JSONTokener;


import com.example.tstnetconnwithjson.tables.custome;
import com.example.tstnetconnwithjson.tables.videos;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.AlertDialog.Builder;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {



    Button search; ; 
    TextView name ; 
    ListView listview ; 
    ArrayList<videos > videolist; 
    ArrayAdapter< videos > adapter ; 
    AlertDialog.Builder alert ; 
    ProgressDialog progressdialog ; 
    EditText name;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        videolist = new ArrayList<videos>(); 
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<videos>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 , android.R.id.text1,videolist); 
        name=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        alert = new Builder(this); 
        alert.setTitle("Warnning" ) ; 
        alert.setMessage("You want to connect to the internet ..? " ); 


        alert.setNegativeButton("No ", null); 
        alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                String username=name.getText().toString();
                            new connection().execute("https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?author="+username+"&v=2&alt=jsonc");   

            }
        });



        progressdialog = new ProgressDialog(this); 

        progressdialog.setMessage("Wait Loading .... "); 
        progressdialog.setCancelable(false); 





        search = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1); 
        name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1); 

        listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1); 

        listview.setAdapter(adapter); 


        search.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View arg0) {
            alert.show();   


            }
        });
    }

    class connection extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>{


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
             progressdialog.show(); 
            super.onPreExecute();
        }
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {

            String s = GetUrlBody(arg0[0]); 




            return s;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        try{

            JSONObject jo =(JSONObject) new JSONTokener(result).nextValue();

        JSONObject feed = jo.optJSONObject("data");
        JSONArray entry = feed.optJSONArray("items");


        for(int i = 0 ; i<entry.length() ; i++){

        String title = entry.getJSONObject(i).getString("title");

        String thumbURL = entry.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("thumbnail").getString("sqDefault");
        Log.d("after get image", "ok")
        String   url;
        try {
            url = entry.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("player").getString("mobile");
        } catch (JSONException ignore) {
            url = entry.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("player").getString("default");
        }

        String description = entry.getJSONObject(i).getString("description");
        Log.d("after get description", "ok");
        videos videoobject=new videos();
        videoobject.setDecscrption(description);
        videoobject.setImageurl(thumbURL);
        videoobject.setVediourl(url);
        videoobject.setVideoname(title);

        videolist.add(videoobject);
        }
        listview.setAdapter(new custome(MainActivity.this,videolist));
        Log.d("AFTER set custome ", "before notify changes");


        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); 

        }catch(Exception exception) {
            Log.d("exception ", "nock nock nock....");
            Log.e("json ", exception.getMessage()); 
        }

            progressdialog.dismiss(); 
            super.onPostExecute(result); 

        } 




        String GetUrlBody (String Url ){

            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(); 

            HttpGet gethttp = new HttpGet(Url); 

            try{
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(gethttp); 

            if(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200){

                String save =
            EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity(), HTTP.UTF_8); 

                return save; 

            }else {
                return "Not Found"; 
            }

            }catch(Exception exception){}




            return null; 
        }



    }


}
```

Where the custome class is extends from base adapter in order to have list view with image view set to  video image  and text view set to video title.
In log cat messages the result are existed but my list view returns empty.
Can any one tell me why?
here is the code for costume list view:

```
public class custome extends BaseAdapter {



    ArrayList<videos> data=new ArrayList<videos>();
    android.content.Context context1;
    android.widget.TextView name;
    ImageView  picture;

    public custome(Context context,ArrayList<videos>arrayList) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        context=context;
        arrayList=data;
    }




    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return data.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return data.get(arg0);
    }

    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return arg0;
    }

    public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
        View view=arg1;

        if(view==null)
        {   
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater=(LayoutInflater) _c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            view=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.listvideo,null); 
        }
        name=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        picture=(ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        videos video = data.get(arg0);
        name.setText(video.getVideoname());


        URL url = null;
        try {
            url = new URL(video.getImageurl());
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        try {
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        picture.setImageBitmap(bitmap);





        return view;
    }

}
```

Comment: have you checked base adapter?? are you getting data in that getView method??

Comment: @ArmaanStranger: Yes I am getting the data correctly but there is nothing in my list view.

Comment: -M-WaJeEh: Am doing a specific task to my company the only thing that they allowed to use is this.

Comment: ok check my answer your problem is solved... silly mistake though :P

Comment: Silly question where is your answer?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33982/discussion-between-m-wajeeh-and-tolen)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your assigning code of `custome` constructor:

Use this constructor:

```
public custome(Context context,ArrayList<videos> arrayList) { 
        context=context;
        //arrayList=data;<<< WRONG
        data=arrayList;//<<<<<<< Correct way of assigning
 }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot I have missed that.:))

Comment: I want to ask you why in my list view some of the images do not appear in it. Despite the parsing gives me the correct URL of each video?

Comment: Well first of all you are getting your images in `getView()` from the network. Which is very very very bad. Don't ever do network call on UI thread. And secondly you should and must use some library to manage and cache bitmaps. I suggest using Volley as it can be used for both purposes. Use it for all of your network calls, it will also manage your image caching etc....

Answer (score 0):

You are overriding your adapter here:

```
listview.setAdapter(new custome(MainActivity.this,videolist));
```

Remove this line

Comment: If I remove this line I will get an ordinary list view . actually what I am trying to do is the next: a list view similar to the one when you enter the YouTube and search about some video.